# Flask-Mail extension of flask not working in application factory structure

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail

What I am trying to do is to configure my flask-mail extension in application factory in order to send mail from different .py files but I am unable to do so.I know my configuration are right because I had same config settings when using single file structure
`__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail,Message
def create_app():
    mail = Mail()
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT']=465
    app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL']=True
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = ''
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = ''
    app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = ''
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False 
    mail.init_app(app)
    return app
```

and the file I am willing to send emails from:
**dev.py**

```py
from flask import *
@bp.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        emailid = request.form['emailid']
        msg = Message('Password Change', sender = '')
        msg.add_recipient(emailid)
        msg.html = "<b>MADHAV</b>"
        mail.send(msg)
```

The error I am receiving is following:

```
NameError: name 'Message' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4):

By looking at the imports you forgot to add the `Message` object in there.

If that s the only error you get, the following line should solve the issue.

**dev.py**

`from flask-mail import Message`